# Spans not being sent to zipkin

Tags: java, spring-boot, zipkin

I need to use Zipkn Serve to trace my spring boot application.Here is my configurations of application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
   config:
     uri: http://localhost:8080
     profiles:
      active: default
management:
  security:
    enabled: false
   zipkin:
   base-url: http://localhost:8082
   sleuth:
sampler:
  percentage: 1.0
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
       cloud:
        sleuth: WARN
```

But the spans not being created in Zipkin.I have added all the required dependencies to my service's pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and the zipkin service's pom file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 approaches to this

1. Start Zipkin server with SpringBootApplication
2. Start Zipkin server as a standalone and add url in SpringBootServer

Looking at your yml file you have added

```
zipkin:
   base-url: http://localhost:8082
```

which means your approach is 2.

But then in your pom, you have added `zipkin-server` and `zipkin-autoconfigure-ui` dependencies which is not required.

I will try to separate both setups

**1. To Start Zipkin server with SpringBootApplication**

**pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
    </dependency>


  <dependency>
        <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
        <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.application.name=zipkin-server
server.port=9411
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZipkinStreamServe
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZipkinServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**2. To Start Zipkin server as a standalone and use SpringBootApplication as Zipkin Client**

[Start Zipkin server](https://zipkin.io/pages/quickstart.html)

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.zipkin.base-url=http://localhost:9411/
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1
```

**Edit 1:**

`@EnableZipkinServer` is deprecated and unsupported as per Brian Devins's comment. So, please go through the [doc](https://zipkin.io/pages/existing_instrumentations.html) for more detail info.

Comment: `@EnableZipkinServer` is deprecated and unsupported. Please do not advocate for it's use. It adds burden to our small community

Comment: Sorry about that. I referred these to get info  https://www.baeldung.com/tracing-services-with-zipkin . and this  https://spring.io/blog/2016/02/15/distributed-tracing-with-spring-cloud-sleuth-and-spring-cloud-zipkin its mentioned   "Using that is as simple as using Zipkin’s @EnableZipkinServer directly. "

Comment: Yeah, there are a large number of blogs that advocate for this approach. I have it on a todo list to try to contact the owners of these blogs about adding a disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

I can say your YAML has some bad indentation and things are not in the right sections even. Otherwise though, you are trying to run Zipkin in an unsupported configuration. Please check out our quickstart documentation: https://zipkin.io/pages/quickstart.html

Comment: I corrected indentations and still not working.what do you mean by  unsupported configuration?

Comment: `@EnableZipkinServer` is deprecated and unsupported. Our community is too small to help debug peoples custom servers. We release official servers that should support most use cases for this reason.

Comment: @cat1197 , Can you add one log of your application here ? . Which port your zipkin service is running ?